# Jquery check if array contains duplicate string

Tags: jquery, arrays

How to check if array contains a duplicate string , i have validateArray = ['sa','sa','yu'] i have used 
the following function from SO but same not working for me.

```
checkDuplicate = function (reportRecipients) {
    if (reportRecipients.length > 1) {
        var recipientsArray = reportRecipients.toString().split(',');
        for (a in recipientsArray) {
            if(reportRecipients.indexOf(a) != reportRecipients.lastIndexOf(a)){
                return true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to find duplicate values in a JavaScript array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array)

Comment: does it work for string also..

Comment: Yes it does work for string as well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
var reportRecipients = ['AAA', 'XYZ', 'AAA', 'ABC', 'XXX', 'XYZ', 'PQR'];
var recipientsArray = reportRecipients.sort(); 

var reportRecipientsDuplicate = [];
for (var i = 0; i < recipientsArray.length - 1; i++) {
    if (recipientsArray[i + 1] == recipientsArray[i]) {
        reportRecipientsDuplicate.push(recipientsArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, if the sort function is not working well :

```
    var all_list= ['sa','sa','yu'] 
    var duplicates_list = [];
    var unique_list = [];
    $.each(all_list, function(key, value){
            if($.inArray(value, unique_list ) == -1){
                unique_list.push(value);
            }else{
                if($.inArray(value, duplicates_list ) == -1){
                    duplicates_list.push(value);
                }
            }
    });

//duplicated elements 
console.log(duplicates_list )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if an array has duplicates using `$.unique` function on jQuery.

```js
let len1 = myArray.length; //get the length of your array
let len2 = $.unique(myArray).length; //the length of array removing the duplicates

if (len1 > len2) {
  alert('Found duplicate');
} else {
  alert('Did not find duplicate');
}
```

Comment: This does not work, it is meant for DOM objects. See https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.uniqueSort/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
function getDistinctArray(arr) {
    var compareArray = new Array();
    if (arr.length > 1) {
        for (i = 0;i < arr.length;i++) {
            if (compareArray.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1) {
                compareArray.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return compareArray;
}
```

And here is a **[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/8Un8G/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
    var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4];
    var chk = new Set();
    var duplicates = arr.filter(n => chk.size === chk.add(n).size);
    //console.log(duplicates); // [ 5 ]
    //console.log(duplicates.length); // 1
    if(duplicates.length > 0){
        alert('Duplicate Found');
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
```

This Working fine. it is the best shortest method .

Answer (score 0):

A simple and clean solution

```
var fileredArray = myArray.filter(function (elem, index, self) {
    return index === self.indexOf(elem);
});
```

Demo:

```
var myArray = [10, 20, 30, 10];

//also works with strings (case sensitive!)
var myArray = ['Amsterdam', 'Paris', 'London', 'Paris'];

//check for duplicates
var fileredArray = myArray.filter(function (elem, index, self) {
    return index === self.indexOf(elem);
});

//show warning if 1 or more duplicate found
if (fileredArray.length < myArray.length) {
    alert('Duplicates found.')
}

//logging
console.log(myArray);
console.log(fileredArray);
```

Answer (score -6):

just use unique() method.

```
$.unique(reportRecipients);
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/