# Writing arrays only one time. jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to write array elements only one time. Such as if i want to write 3 it should write once only. Is it possible achiving it using array.

**my code**

```
var arr = [ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4];

arr = $.grep(arr, function( x, y ) {
  return ( x !== 1);
});
$( "p>span" ).text( arr.join( ", " ) );
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tuxsanov/JY49B/);

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to remove duplicate values from the array?

Comment: yes sure is it possible?

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you mean that you want to remove duplicate values from your array you can use the `$.unique` helper in jQuery:

```
var arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4];
$("p > span").text($.unique(arr));
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JY49B/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Oh well - I am little bit too late. But here's an alternative - if you are using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq):

```
_.uniq([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]);
```

Or use a filter:

```
var unique=a.filter(function(itm,i,a){
    return i==a.indexOf(itm);
});
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381621/jquery-function-to-get-all-unique-elements-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var result = [];
 $.each(arr, function(i, e) {if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);});
 return result;
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JY49B/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22980069/1777090)

```
var arr = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,1,1];
var sorted_arr= arr.sort(); 

var newArr= [];
for (var i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
        newArr.push(sorted_arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code updated here   [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JY49B/5/) ..

```
function eliminateDuplicates(arr) {
  var i,
      len=arr.length,
      out=[],
      obj={};

  for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
    obj[arr[i]]=0;
  }
  for (i in obj) {
    out.push(i);
  }
  return out;
}
```